# JavaScript: Incorrect Dates

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, mysql, vb.net

I have a hosted web application that generates reports based on daily end of business day data. With the server located in Europe (set to use UTC time), me located in Asia (UTC+5) and my boss and peers located in the US (UTC-5), we seem to have a problem getting the same dates.

For example, the report on my side shows "July 23, 2012" while in the US it shows "July 22, 2012". I checked on the server using RDP, and it shows "July 23, 2012" as well.

There's no localization within my app. I'm not sure if this is ASP.NET, client-side JavaScript or MySql that's changing the dates based on where the request originates from? Any ideas?

**Edit**
Just checked with my boss, the source within his browser shows "2012-07-23" as well. So I suppose that narrows it down to JavaScript changing the dates when `new Date("2012-07-23")` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using ISO Datetime please make sure you specify a timezone on the end, otherwise it's counted as local time.

If possible when using databases and ASP.NET applications use UTC time for everything.

```
GETUTCDATE() 

DateTime.UTCNow()
```

If your specifying dates for use, then use ISO dates whenever possible to cut down on cultural invariances.

Comment: Thanks, John. But if the server is globally set to UTC timezone, do I still need UTCNow()? Also, it might be worth mentioning that it's 2012-07-24 here in my timezone, but the reports still show 2012-07-23 on my computer and the server's browser. The issue only seems to affect my colleagues that are in the US (Eastern Time). No matter what day it is, the date gets translated for them as -1. Even though UTC and Eastern Time are on the same date right now.

Comment: Its always worth using UTCNow() since then the machines don't matter what time zone they are in, they are all using the same base.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can blame your JavaScript code. Using the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/) like you (`new Date("2012-07-23")`) with a string calls [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), which uses the local timezone if none is specified.

Use ISO timestamps or milliseconds since epoch instead.

Of course, the displaying has another role. When you output utc time, parsed as the local timezone, as local time, it will show utc "correctly". If you output a utc-parsed utc-string as local time, it will correctly show the local time.

Comment: Tried using milliseconds, still didn't help. Could this be some browser side behavior?

Comment: How did you output the Date object? UTC-string, local date-string? Please show us that code, too.